# のです and te-form + よい

Tags: grammar, particles

彼は冬に何日かお休みがあります。

彼は2週間仕事をしなくてよいのです。

What is the grammar behind しなくてよい? Does it mean "doesn't have to work?" Also is のです being used because the fact that he doesn't have to work for 2 weeks explains 冬に何日かお休みがあります?

Answer (score 2):

> 「彼{かれ}は冬{ふゆ}に何日{なんにち}かお休{やす}みがあります。
>
> 彼は2週間仕事{しゅうかんしごと}をしなくてよいのです。」

「しなくてよい」＝する + ない + て + よい

「し」 is the 連用形{れんようけい} ("continuative form") of 「する」 just as 「なく」 is that of 「ない」.

The super-literal meaning of 「しなくてよい」 would be something like "***if not do (something),  good/okay***".

That is why 「しなくてよい」 is often translated as "***to not have to do ~~***" in natural English.  One would agree that it is a valid translation, wouldn't one?

> Also is のです being used because the fact that he doesn't have to work for 2 weeks explains 冬に何日かお休みがあります?

Exactly.  Except for the 「２週間」 part, which is a more detailed piece of information, the second sentence is basically just rephrasing the first.

I might add that this passage was clearly written/spoken for a non-native-speaker.